# Custom/common toolbar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, toolbar

I'm quite new to Swift and am working on an app where I'm not sure how to setup the navigation. It works with a tab bar, except that I want the bar to display nomatter what view is being displayed. There are 4 "main" views that the user should always be able to get to. The problem comes when I get into subviews of one of those main views.

I have the tab bar with the 4 icons for the primary views. It's currently displaying the "activity list". When the user clicks on an activity, it will display a list at the next level of detail. However, that view is not one of the primary ones that is represented in the tab bar, so it has no tab bar and no way to transition directly to one of the primary views. You have to back your way out to the Activity list before you can select a different tab.

Say that the main views (represented in the tab bar) are A, B, C, and D. I want to be able to display the same toolbar on all sub-views (e.g. C-1, C-2, etc.) and allow direct transition to any of the other main views, without the user having to manually back out of each sub-view.

What is the "best" way to accomplish this? 
1) Should I be creating a custom toolbar object that gets implemented on every view controller? 
2) Should it be a combination of tab bar and tool bars? 
3) If I have drilled into a stack of views, do I need to pop all of those views individually before I can switch to a different tab?
4) What do I use as my "root" view?

Thanks for any suggestions. I have hunted, but haven't found an example of a scenario quite like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I needed to embed each "tab" view in a navigation controller.

So...
Tab Bar Controller --> Navigation Controller --> View Controller --> "view stack"

The tab bar now remains at the bottom for every view, and if I touch the tab icon a second time, it goes back to the original tab view controller.